# initializing scanner values in a loop to an array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have created a game where the user guesses a random number that was created 0-100. If their guess is too high, the system tells them to guess higher, and the same for if their guess is lower than the actual number. However, I need to initialize each guess to an array, in the order that they inputted. I know how to initialize an array, but I need help on storing the player's guesses into the array. Here is my code, and any help/advice is appreciated!

```
public static void randomNumGame(){
    // begin of method

    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int[] guess;
    guess = new int[6];
    guess[0]=0;
    guess[1]=0;
    guess[2]=0;
    guess[3]=0;
    guess[4]=0;
    guess[5]=0;

    System.out.println("running ...");
    int thisRandomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    int attempt = 0;
    boolean done = false;

    while(!done){
        System.out.print("Guess a number from 0 to 100 : ");

        int myGuess = numbers.nextInt();
        attempt++;

        if(myGuess == thisRandomInt && attempt <= guess.length){
            done = true;
            System.out.println("You won. It took " + attempt+ " times to guess my number.");
        }else if (attempt >= guess.length){
            System.out.println("Game Over. My number is "+thisRandomInt );
            done = true;
        }else if (myGuess < thisRandomInt){
            System.out.println("Guess a higher number");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Guess a lower number");
        }
    }
}// end of method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(myGuess == thisRandomInt && attempt <= guess.length){
    done = true;
    System.out.println("You won. It took " + attempt+ " times to guess my number.");
}else if (attempt >= guess.length){
    System.out.println("Game Over. My number is "+thisRandomInt );
    done = true;
}else if (myGuess < thisRandomInt){
    guess[attempt-1] = myGuess;
    System.out.println("Guess a higher number");
}else{
    guess[attempt-1] = myGuess;
    System.out.println("Guess a lower number");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly init your quest array with zeroes. Apart from that, you can do something like this:

```
    System.out.print("Guess a number from 0 to 100 : ");

    int myGuess = numbers.nextInt();
    guess[attempt++] = myGuess;
```

Also, instead of the `done` flag, you can call `break` instead of declaring the flag `true` - it will escape the loop.